# MySQL server lost power, partial data loss

Tags: mysql, crash, data-loss

I had a server running mysql.  The power was cut to the machine, and mysql (I assume was forced to terminate)

Now, when I try to connect to the database again, the tables exist, but there doesn't appear to be anything in the tables, would there be any chance of a way to fix this.
When I use the `SHOW TABLES` command, it lists the corrupted table.  When I use the `SELECT * FROM [corrupted table]` it says table does not exist.

I understand if it seems impossible (please let me know if so)

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

in such case we retrive a data from log file:

```
1) [This is first link][1],
2) [This is main URL][2]
```

Comment: Where is the log file on Mac OS X?